# How to provide alternative layout resources

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a requirement where I have to provide different `layout` resources with my application.

This application is supposed to run on many screen sizes (as always) and I want to be able to address many of them as precisely as possible.

As of now, I am targeting following screen sizes:

- 1280x800
- 800x480
- 800x600
- 1024x600

For this, I created a layout structure like this:

[image: Layout structure]

And in XML, I have declared the following support:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

I am testing in it emulator and the problem is: it accepts `layout-w480dp-land` xml, but when I go in portrait mode, it falls back to default layout.

Any idea where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the `Android` Chatroom, `Pixels` and `Density-independent pixel (dp)` are different:

> Density-independent pixel (dp)
>
> A virtual pixel unit that you should
>   use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position
>   in a density-independent way. The density-independent pixel is
>   equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the
>   baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen.
>   At runtime, the system transparently handles any scaling of the dp
>   units, as necessary, based on the actual density of the screen in use.
>   The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi
>   / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical
>   pixels. You should always use dp units when defining your
>   application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with
>   different densities.

When you have a folder named layout-w480dp what you're saying is:

> "Use this layout folder as long as the width dimension is equal to or greater than 480 **dp**."

Now, if you have a device with 240dpi with a screen size 480x800 pixels (which is very likely) then you actually only have **320dp** to play with - explaining why you're folder is now being skipped.

> dp = px / (dpi / 160)

320dp = 480px / (240dpi / 160)

Comment: A very valid reason. Now I get what you were trying to say. So in your case, how do I know which one to target, 320dp or 480dp?

Answer (score 1):

I can refer you to one of the Google I/O 2011 session from Reto Meier:

> One way to support the latest devices while also supporting older
>   versions is to use a "shim" activity that determines what platform the
>   device is running. It doesn't have a UI. Reto shows some code for
>   launching different activities based on system version. This is a
>   parallel activity pattern...

[Link to session](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-protips-advanced-topics-for-expert-android-app-developers.html) - His presentation is also available to download, the parallel pattern principle start from slide 10

Answer (score 0):

I have heard about below layout resources:

```
res/layout-sw600dp
res/layout-sw720dp
```

Not sure about your problem but i haven't heard about **w480dp**, it may be **sw480dp**.

Comment: `sw480dp` works for the case where "smalles" width available is 480dp, `w480dp` works when the current width is around 480dp or more. and the default emulator is at `480x800` in portrait mode

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).
mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi   Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
```

instead of w480dp

and follow following table.
[Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

Comment: I don't think this is what I am asking here.
If you're talking about `drawable` resources, I am not concerned about them. I am concerned about `layout` depending upon the screen size

Comment: This applies to layout resources as well. Kindly read provided link

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never did it your way, but what I do is measure Screen Size and density on run time and apply the layout in onCreate()  in the beginning.
Here is the code for your reference and might help you out:

```
    /**
     * To acknowledge the density of the application so as to use the layout
     * according to the phone density
     */
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    switch(metrics.densityDpi){
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
             setContentView(R.layout.x);
                    break;
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
             setContentView(R.layout.y);
                     break;
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
             setContentView(R.layout.z);
                     break;
```

Comment: That is a nice option, but for some reasons I would want to do it via the XML. I would keep this one as the backup option though :D

Comment: For layout way also, try using: <res/layout-large-land> instead of <layout-w480dp-land> and for your needs try res/layout/ or res/layout-small/ or res/layout-large/ or res/layout-xlarge/ according to your needs where xlarge takes around 720p size screens. I'm quite sure replacing will work out and for landscape try suffixing <-land>. Cheers

Comment: I tried the `large-land` way and it just didn't work. fell back to default one. Moreover, they've deprecated this qualifiers quite a lot after 3.x

Comment: Yes true, I just realised for 3.x onwards rules have changed. The manual also states that you need to specify:- **Declaring screen size support**

Once you've implemented your layouts for different screen sizes, it's equally important that you declare in your manifest file which screens your application supports: <android:requiresSmallestWidthDp> Eg:<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
    ...
</manifest>
**Specifies the minimum smallestWidth required.**

Comment: Since, you are not mentioning the above line it drops to the smallest layout. As per documentation:
**However, if your application supports all screen sizes supported by Android (as small as 426dp x 320dp), then you don't need to declare this attribute, because the smallest width your application requires is the smallest possible on any device.**