# providing resources for different devices

Tags: android, xml, layout, scaling

I have received reports of my app not scaling properly on a specific device, the galaxy s 2 and I am trying to make a new layout for devices with similar resolutions. I have been reading this site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources and I have tried making folders called /layout-w480dp and /layout-sw480dp but the new layout never is picked up in the emulator that i have set with a width of 480 dp. What should the folder be called so that on a device with a width of 480 that layout is used instead of a scaled version of the default layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct layout-identifier to use for the s2 is:

```
layout-sw320
```

It's HDPI so the scaling factor is 1.5. The resolution is 480x800, so the calculation is (480 / 1.5), which equals 320.

Comment: Damn! I thought that was a good guess :) You realise width of 480 pixels != 480dp right? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11189425/833647

Comment: oh ok thanks for that link. now the only issue is converting the ppi to dpi.. i found the ppi online which is 218

Comment: For s2 I believe you need to use `layout-sw320`. It's HDPI so the scaling factor is 1.5, so the calculation is (480 / 1.5), which equals 320

Comment: Cool! I've edited my answer in case you feel like accepting it.